# Is there a metric $\rho$ on $X$ sequentially equivalent to $d$ such that $F:(X,\rho)\to (X,\rho)$ is a $\lambda$-contraction?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

Suppose $F:(X,d) \to (X,d)$ a Lipschitz application with Lipschitz constant $L>1$. Is there a metric $\rho$ on $X$ sequentially equivalent to $d$ such that $F:(X,\rho)\to (X,\rho)$ is a $\lambda$-contraction?

The motivation for this question is the following. If $F: (X,\rho) \to (X,\rho)$ is a contraction then by Banach's fixed point theorem $F: (X,\rho) \to (X,\rho)$ has a fixed point at $(X,\rho)$.  And since $\rho$ is sequentially equivalent to $d$ then $F:(X,d)\to (X,d)$ has a fixed point at (X,d).  If this motivation is correct and the answer to the question is affirmative, then the conclusion is that every Lipschitz application of a metric space itself has a single fixed point.

But I believe that such a conclusion is not possible because if it were, analysis textbooks would not restrict the Banach's Fixed Point Theorem to contractive applications.

> **QUESTION.** Any explanation for any negative answer to the above question? If the answer to the question is yes, any explanation for why the Analysis textbooks do not explore the fixed-point result mentioned above?

Comment: Have you tried any examples?

Comment: What do you mean by "sequentially equivalent"? Just the usual equivalence of metrics?

Comment: @PaulFrost See the post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3798285/are-these-two-metrics-equivalent

Comment: So it is the same as "the metrics are equivalent".